# How to add button to article information?

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation, filter

I have to add Layered Navigation to another product category.

[image]

If I click on `Category -> Manage Article` in the backend and select a product, then I see this site:

[image: Backend]

As you can see there are two filters which are not normally there, they were added by an agency which works with my company. But I can't figure out how to add one on my own since I'm fairly new to Magento.

Those are two filters for two categories, and I need another one.

I searched the whole project for the string "Filter Fliesenkleber" by using Notepad++ but I only found 1 occurrence in an SQL file.

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_group` VALUES (1,1,'General',1,1),(2,2,'General',1,1),(3,3,'General Information',10,1),(4,4,'General',1,1),(5,4,'Preise',4,0),(6,4,'Meta Information',5,0),(7,4,'Images',6,0),(8,4,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',7,0),(9,4,'Design',8,0),(10,3,'Display Settings',20,0),(11,3,'Custom Design',30,0),(12,5,'General',1,1),(13,6,'General',1,1),(14,7,'General',1,1),(15,8,'General',1,1),(16,4,'Gift Options',9,0),(17,9,'General',1,1),(18,9,'Preise',4,0),(19,9,'Meta Information',6,0),(20,9,'Images',7,0),(21,9,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(22,9,'Design',9,0),(23,9,'Gift Options',10,0),(24,9,'Tabelle',2,0),(25,10,'General',1,1),(26,10,'Preise',4,0),(27,10,'Meta Information',6,0),(28,10,'Images',7,0),(29,10,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(30,10,'Design',9,0),(31,10,'Gift Options',10,0),(32,10,'Tabelle',2,0),(33,11,'General',1,1),(34,11,'Preise',5,0),(35,11,'Meta Information',6,0),(36,11,'Images',7,0),(37,11,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(38,11,'Design',9,0),(39,11,'Gift Options',10,0),(40,11,'Tabelle',3,0),(41,12,'General',1,1),(42,12,'Preise',4,0),(43,12,'Meta Information',6,0),(44,12,'Images',7,0),(45,12,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(46,12,'Design',9,0),(47,12,'Gift Options',10,0),(48,12,'Tabelle',2,0),(49,13,'General',1,1),(50,13,'Preise',4,0),(51,13,'Meta Information',6,0),(52,13,'Images',7,0),(53,13,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(54,13,'Design',9,0),(55,13,'Gift Options',10,0),(56,13,'Tabelle',2,0),(57,14,'General',1,1),(58,14,'Preise',4,0),(59,14,'Meta Information',6,0),(60,14,'Images',7,0),(61,14,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(62,14,'Design',9,0),(63,14,'Gift Options',10,0),(64,14,'Tabelle',2,0),(65,15,'General',1,1),(66,15,'Preise',4,0),(67,15,'Meta Information',6,0),(68,15,'Images',7,0),(69,15,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(70,15,'Design',9,0),(71,15,'Gift Options',10,0),(72,15,'Tabelle',2,0),(73,16,'General',1,1),(74,16,'Preise',4,0),(75,16,'Meta Information',5,0),(76,16,'Images',6,0),(77,16,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',7,0),(78,16,'Design',8,0),(79,16,'Gift Options',9,0),(80,16,'Tabelle',2,0),(81,17,'General',1,1),(82,17,'Preise',4,0),(83,17,'Meta Information',6,0),(84,17,'Images',7,0),(85,17,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(86,17,'Design',9,0),(87,17,'Gift Options',10,0),(88,17,'Tabelle',2,0),(89,18,'General',1,1),(90,18,'Preise',4,0),(91,18,'Meta Information',5,0),(92,18,'Images',6,0),(93,18,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',7,0),(94,18,'Design',8,0),(95,18,'Gift Options',9,0),(96,18,'Tabelle',2,0),(97,19,'General',1,1),(98,19,'Preise',5,0),(99,19,'Meta Information',6,0),(100,19,'Images',7,0),(101,19,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(102,19,'Design',9,0),(103,19,'Gift Options',10,0),(104,19,'Tabelle',3,0),(105,20,'General',1,1),(106,20,'Preise',4,0),(107,20,'Meta Information',6,0),(108,20,'Images',7,0),(109,20,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',8,0),(110,20,'Design',9,0),(111,20,'Gift Options',10,0),(112,20,'Tabelle',2,0),(113,21,'General',1,1),(114,21,'Preise',4,0),(115,21,'Meta Information',5,0),(116,21,'Images',6,0),(117,21,'Wiederkehrendes Profil',7,0),(118,21,'Design',8,0),(119,21,'Gift Options',9,0),(120,21,'Tabelle',2,0),(121,9,'Shipping',11,0),(122,10,'Shipping',11,0),(123,11,'Shipping',11,0),(124,12,'Shipping',11,0),(125,13,'Shipping',11,0),(126,14,'Shipping',11,0),(127,15,'Shipping',11,0),(128,16,'Shipping',10,0),(129,17,'Shipping',11,0),(130,18,'Shipping',10,0),(131,19,'Shipping',11,0),(132,20,'Shipping',11,0),(133,21,'Shipping',10,0),(134,4,'Shipping',10,0),(135,9,'Prices',12,0),(136,10,'Prices',12,0),(137,11,'Prices',12,0),(138,12,'Prices',12,0),(139,13,'Prices',12,0),(140,14,'Prices',12,0),(141,15,'Prices',12,0),(142,16,'Prices',11,0),(143,17,'Prices',12,0),(144,18,'Prices',11,0),(145,19,'Prices',12,0),(146,20,'Prices',12,0),(147,21,'Prices',11,0),(148,4,'Prices',11,0),(149,9,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(150,10,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(151,11,'Beschreibungstexte',4,0),(152,12,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(153,13,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(154,14,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(155,15,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(156,16,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(157,17,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(158,18,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(159,19,'Beschreibungstexte',4,0),(160,20,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(161,21,'Beschreibungstexte',3,0),(162,4,'Filter Fliesenkleber',2,0),(163,9,'Price Calculator',13,0),(164,18,'Price Calculator',12,0),(165,4,'Price Calculator',12,0),(166,16,'Price Calculator',12,0),(167,11,'Zuschnitt-Preise',13,0),(168,13,'Price Calculator',13,0),(169,12,'Price Calculator',13,0),(170,17,'Price Calculator',13,0),(171,15,'Price Calculator',13,0),(172,19,'Price Calculator',13,0),(173,10,'Price Calculator',13,0),(174,21,'Price Calculator',12,0),(175,20,'Price Calculator',13,0),(176,14,'Price Calculator',13,0),(177,4,'Filter Fliesenschiene',3,0),(178,13,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',5,0),(179,9,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',5,0),(180,10,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',5,0),(181,12,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',5,0),(182,20,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',5,0),(183,11,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',2,0),(184,17,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',5,0),(185,14,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',5,0),(186,19,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',2,0),(187,15,'Maßeinheiten pflegen',5,0);
```

Where is it possibly defined? In the database?

How can I make a new button "Filter Ausgleichsmasse" below the two buttons inside the red rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following steps:

1. Goto Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets.
2. Then edit the Default attribute set
3. You can now create new group by clicking "New Group" button. Also you can move the new group where you want by dragging it.
4. After that you can add attribute(s) to that group and click on "Save Attribute Set"
5. Now goto product and check that the new group is now showing to the left side.